Why does adding a new route on macOS not affect existing TCP and UDP connections?
This shouldn't be happening since routing is IP-level phenomenon, and yet it does:

Establish a TCP (or even UDP!) connection:
nc 1.2.3.4 1234

Observe that you can send and receive data via this connection by typing on console and checking the other end of the connection

Create a new route
sudo route add -reject 1.2.3.4 127.0.0.1

Observe that the connection established in step 1 is still working

Try creating a new connection to the same host and observe that it's not transmitting data as expected.


I've tried this many times, including with UDP sockets and the behavior is consistently reproducible. Nothing like this happens on Linux or Windows (as one would expect). The only explanation I have is that there's some special handling of TCP and UDP packets in the OS routing mechanism or something like per-process routing tables. But I can't find any mention of that anywhere. Is there documentation on this behavior and how to change it? Or an alternative explanation?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Turns out the routing information is indeed cached on per-socket basis in the BSD network stack. It's stored in a structure called inpcb (Internet Protocol Control Block?) attached to every socket. In Darwin, this is defined in bsd/netinet/in_pcb.h.
